# How to querying the database inside the makeApplication function

Tags: haskell, persistent, yesod, persist

I'm attempting to fork a non-web service in my Yesod application, and it needs to do some interaction with database.  From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969734/where-to-add-always-running-thread-to-yesod-applications) post I decided to put the service in makeApplication.  I would like my service to return some value when certain things happen and store it into database.  Thus, I'm wondering whats the best way to do this?

How do I run `runDB $ insert $ Stuff (T.pack "stuff")` inside the makeApplication function?

EDIT:
As suggested by Michael I made the following helper function inside Application.hs

```
runDBIO conf foundation f = do
    dbconf <- withYamlEnvironment "config/postgresql.yml" (appEnv conf)
        Database.Persist.loadConfig >>=
        Database.Persist.applyEnv
    p <- Database.Persist.createPoolConfig (dbconf :: Settings.PersistConf)
    logger <- mkLogger True stdout

    runLoggingT
        (Database.Persist.runPool dbconf f p)
        (messageLoggerSource foundation logger)
```

And in the makeApplication I used it like so:

```
runDBIO conf foundation $ do
    dbid <- insert $ Stuff (T.pack "some random stuff")
    string <- get dbid
    liftIO $ print string
```

However, I'm getting this compile error:

```
No instance for (resourcet-0.4.5:Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.MonadResource IO)
arising from a use of 'insert'
```

Am I inputting the wrong type for runPool? Or I need to make an instance for `insert`?
I don't see why `runMigration migrateAll` works but `insert` does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see a demonstration of how to run a database action in the `IO` monad in [the scaffolding itself](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod-scaffold/blob/postgres/Application.hs#L65). Essentially you need to provide two pieces of information: how to log queries, and the database connection pool. You could factor that code out into a helper function (e.g., `runDBIO`), and then run `runDBIO $ insert $ Stuff $ T.pack "stuff"`.

Comment: That sounds cool, I'll give it a try!  Question, what's your standing on helper functions?  I've always thought it was an anti pattern.

Comment: Perhaps our definitions of helper functions are different. I just meant a function that factors out some common code, which I definitely wouldn't consider an anti pattern.

Comment: Yes it makes perfect sense to create a function if it's common code.  Maybe what I mean about helper function is like in Java, people make utility classes, putting lots of unrelated functions into the same class.

Comment: Putting runResourceT in front of runDBIO solved the problem thanks, referencing this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047095/haskell-persistent-sqlite-no-instance-for-control-monad-trans-resource-mona).